# Pass 'continue' from inside a function to the outer loop in Python

Tags: python, function, loops, continue

I hope i can express myself accordingly, as I'm quite new to programming and I'm sure the answer is quite simple but I can't get there... :)
So I have a 'for' loop that executes some functions. Each function has an 'if' statement in it and only does something, if the conditions allow so.
What I want is the loop to reset, as soon as a function's 'if' statement is satisfied.

Edit: I messed up the function :( thx for your answers so far ^^
An example of what i wish would work:

```
def do_something():
   if something == True:
      do_some_stuff
      return continue

while i < 999:
   do_something()
   do_something2()
   do_something3()
```

The 'return continue' is the part that doesn't work as I wish and I can't find a solution for that (maybe I don't know what exactly to google for)

Comment: Do you just mean `continue` without the return? You can't return a continue, as it's not a value. It's not even a function.

Comment: Where is the function here? This is just a loop with an if statement. As Silvio says, you can just do `continue` here. As a side note, you can do `if something` rather than `if something == True`.

Comment: Edited the function I failed at before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have 'do_something' return a boolean

```py
def do_something():
   if something is True:
      do_some_stuff
      return True
   return False

while i < 999:
   if do_something():
      continue
   do_something2()
   do_something3()
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no function, so there's nothing to `return`. You can however `break` out of the `while` loop once the condition `something` is met like so:

```
while i < 999:
   if something == True:
      do_some_stuff
      break
```